# why does data segment get corrupted in arm64 when switch down to EL1 from EL2?

Tags: arm64, bare-metal

I use uboot to bringup my baremetal application on rk3588(Radxa RockPi 5b). I use following command to boot up

```bash
fatload mmc 1 0x8300000 rk3588.bin
go 0x8300000
```

I write some freestanding printf function so that I could print some debug information. It turns out that my print function works well in **EL2**. However, if I switch to **EL1** in my baremetal application, I cannot print those data stored in **.data** segment while those located in **.rodata** segment works fine.

I mean:

```c
/**************in EL1***********/
//works well
printf("hello");

//works well if n is local variable
printf("hello %d", n);

//works well as 1234 located in .rodata
printf("hello %d", 1234);

//failed if n is global variable 
printf("hello %d", n);

/**************in EL2***********/
//all these functions above works well in EL2
```

I use **md** command in uboot to make sure all **.data** is load into the memory.

Also I tried to print val in **.data** segment and got all them zeros. Its seems that data segment were zero after I got into **EL1**.

```c
int test_data = 1;

//0x8305000 is where data segment starts
//I got test_data = 0 at last
test_data = *(int *)0x8305000;
printf("test_data = %d", test_data);
```

I am wondering if there is something specially should be done before entering **EL1**. Currently, I just use:

```
prepare_el1:   
    ldr x0, =((1 << 31) | (1 << 41) | (1 << 40))
    msr hcr_el2, x0
    isb

    msr sctlr_el1, xzr
    isb

    ldr x0, =((7<<6) | 5)
    msr spsr_el2, x0
    isb

    adr x0, entry_el1
    msr elr_el2, x0
    isb
    eret
```

At last, I did some tricks: I relocated my program to another place before I use **eret** to get into **EL1**, then the data segment is not changed print function works well.

However, it is still confusing why data segment change into zeros.

Comment: each EL has it's own memory mapping. is your `.data` section mapped to same virtual address space in both EL1 and EL2 ?

Comment: @user3124812 I did not turn on mmu in my baremetal program. If it is related to memory mapping, I think my trick would not works.

Comment: @SONGGY You may have not turned the MMU on, but if you have somecode that may have been executed at EL3 prior to u-boot to be started, usually at EL2, such as Arm Trusted Firmware, in this case, your MMU may well have been activated.

Comment: @SONGGGY  You should check what is the [current EL](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0595/2020-12/AArch64-Registers/CurrentEL--Current-Exception-Level)  when u-boot is running, and if whether or not the [MMU is enabled.](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/den0024/a/The-Memory-Management-Unit/Translating-a-Virtual-Address-to-a-Physical-Address/Configuring-and-enabling-the-MMU).  Would you have any pointer to the source code for the exact versions of ATF or equivalent and u-boot you are using ? What is the brand/model of your SBC, and how did you install u-boot on the SBC ?

Comment: @Frant Hi! My SBC is RockPi 5b and I boot from sd card. As for Uboot and ATF, I use the Radxa official release [here](https://wiki.radxa.com/Rock5/guide/build-u-boot-on-5b). And yes, Uboot turned the MMU on but I turn it off when I switch down to EL1.